# Existing xml format is also changing when I add new node to a file

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

This is my original xml file format

```
<profile>
  <person name="user1" age="x years" 
  job="role1">
  </person> 
  <person name="user2" age="x years" 
  job="role1">
  </person>
</profile>
```

when i try to add new subnode with new attribute values, the existing format also changing as below and adding new node

```
<profile>
  <person name="user1" age="x years" job="role1">
  </person>
  <person name="user2" age="y years" job="role1">
  </person>
  <person name="user3" age="z years" job="role1">
  </person>
</profile>
```

but I want the output in the following format

```
<profile>
  <person name="user1" age="x years" 
  job="role1">
  </person>
  <person name="user2" age="y years" 
  job="role1">
  </person>
  <person name="user3" age="z years" 
  job="role1">
  </person>
</profile>
```

This is the command Iam using...

```
xmlstarlet edit -s '/profile' -t elem -n 'newnode' -s '//newnode' -t text -n '' -v "" \
    -i //newnode -t attr -n "name" -v "user3" \
    -i //newnode -t attr -n "age" -v "z years" \
    -i //newnode -t attr -n "job" -v "role1" \
    -r //newnode -v person \
    file.xml
```

can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

[xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) relies on [libxml2](/questions/tagged/libxml2) for
[serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)
(cf. [API reference](https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/libxml2/devhelp/libxml2-xmlsave.html))
and `xmlstarlet edit` offers 2 formatting options

- `-P` (aka `--pf`) preserve original formatting
  -- sets `libxml2`'s `XML_SAVE_FORMAT` flag
- `-S` (aka `--ps`) preserve non-significant spaces
  -- sets `libxml2`'s `XML_SAVE_WSNONSIG` flag (req. `libxml2` 2.7.8+)

but none of these will produce the output you're after. Combining the
2 options the formatted output appears to match that of
`xmllint --pretty 2 …` (another `libxml2`-based tool) which may be more
suited for manual editing / review -- which probably is your actual goal.
Or you could spend time testing
[XML formatters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prettyprint)
which don't get things *quite* right after all, or perhaps write your own.

Changing your command to `xmlstarlet edit -P -S …` output becomes:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<profile
  >
  <person
      name="user1"
      age="x years"
      job="role1"
    >
  </person
  > 
  <person
      name="user2"
      age="x years"
      job="role1"
    >
  </person
  >
<person
      name="user3"
      age="z years"
      job="role1"
    ></person
  ></profile
>
```

Comment: yes what you mentioned is true and if I run commands using `-P` and `-S` , then the format will be above as you gave above